# Model Equation of logistic regression in sklearn or statsmodel.api

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

After running the logistic regression, I want to see the model equation. Is there a way of finding that?

Comment: Please, provide some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

In sklearn you can access the coefficients and intercept by accessing the `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes as documented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Don't know about statsmodels, but according to the first tutorial that shows up on google [here](https://mashimo.wordpress.com/2017/07/26/logistic-regression-with-python-statsmodels/), you can use the `params` attribute of the result.